# How to make one time call to function in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have made a counter $counter and set its limit to 10. Now After Making a click on screen, I am adding div tag and increasing counter by 1. But along with that I have added a close button on each div and decreasing counter by 1 on each click on div.close. But due to same class .close. But the counter decreases many times in one click.

```
$(canvas).click(function() {
    $counter++;
    if($counter<10)
    $("#color-swatch").prepend("<div>"+color+"<div class='close'></div></div>");
    $(".close").click(function()
    {
        $(this).parent().remove();
        $counter--;
        console.log($counter);

    });
});
```

Output of console on just one click on close div.

10
9 
8 
7
6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is you are binding the click handler to the same element multiple times.

One solution here is to use event delegation instead of binding the handler inside another click handler

```
$(canvas).click(function () {
    $counter++;
    if ($counter < 10) {
        $("#color-swatch").prepend("<div>" + color + "<div class='close'></div></div>");
    }
});

$("#color-swatch").on('click', '.close', function () {
    $(this).parent().remove();
    $counter--;
    console.log($counter);
});
```

---

Another is to target only the newly added element

```
$(canvas).click(function () {
    $counter++;
    if ($counter < 10) {
        var $el = $("<div>" + color + "<div class='close'></div></div>").prependTo("#color-swatch");
        $el.find(".close").click(function () {
            $(this).parent().remove();
            $counter--;
            console.log($counter);

        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `.off()` in jquery and `event delegation` for created dynamic elements

```
$("#color-swatch").on("click" , ".close" , function() {

         $(this).off("click");
         $(this).parent().remove();
        $counter--;
        console.log($counter);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code the close is binded every time the canvas is clicked , so use flag variable or use on one in jquery

```
$(".close").one("click",function(){
```

Or

use flag variable to check is close button is ready to click

```
var isReadyCloseClick = false;
$(canvas).click(function () {
    $counter++;
    if ($counter < 10) {
         $("#color-swatch").prepend("<div>" + color + "<div class='close'></div></div>");
         }
    isReadyCloseClick = true;

});

$("#color-swatch").on("click",".close",function () {
    if (isReadyCloseClick) {
        $(this).parent().remove();
        $counter--;
        console.log($counter);
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because on each click of the `canvas` element you are attaching another handler to the close element. Therefore on the third click of `canvas`, your `close` handler will decrement by 3. You can fix this by putting a single delegated `close` click handler outside of the `canvas` one:

```
$(canvas).click(function() {
    $counter++;
    if ($counter < 10)
        $("#color-swatch").prepend("<div>" + color + "<div class='close'></div></div>");
});

$("#color-swatch").on('click', '.close', function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
    $counter--;
    console.log($counter);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Every time you click on your canvas, you are layering a new click handler on all `.close` elements, new and old. This means that after five clicks on canvas, your first div will decrement counter five times, once per each click handler. Use `$("#color-swatch").on('click', '.close', function(evt) { ... })` to create a living event handler once and for all, that will catch future clicks when you create `.close' elements, and put it outside the canvas click handler.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are adding click handler on every click.
You need to either use `.one()` or use `.off()`

`$(".close").one('click',function()`

or

`$(".close").off('click').on('click',function()`

Answer (score 0):

Use ID rather than class
e.g.

```
$(canvas).click(function() {
$counter++;
if($counter<10){
var clsId="cls_"+$counter;
$("#color-swatch").prepend("<div>"+color+"<div class='close' id='"+clsId+"'></div></div>");
}
$(clsId).click(function()
{
    $(this).parent().remove();
    $counter--;
    console.log($counter);

});
```

});